# Excluding multiple values from the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following codes

```
'delete' => function($url, $model) { 
                        $url = Url::to(['category/delete/'.$model->info_category_id]);
                        return ($model->info_category_id !== 11)?Html::a('<i class="icon-trash"></i>', $url, ['class'=>'black-txt tips del-confirm-subitems']):'';
                    },
```

which are about creating the delete function of a certain category in the backend. As you see in the third line it excludes the category id number 11 from delete function. Beside category id number 11 I would also like to add category id number 15 from the database, however it leads to error when I insert 15 as following:   `($model->info_category_id !== 11, 15)`.

I would appreciate if you could help me to insert category_id number 15 correctly to the codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
return (!in_array($model->info_category_id,[11,15]))?Html::a('<i class="icon-trash"></i>', $url, ['class'=>'black-txt tips del-confirm-subitems']):'';
```

the way you are doing it is incorrect syntax for PHP. The above example uses `in_array` function to determine whether the value of `$model->info_category_id` matches any value inside the provided array.  Or you can try like this:

```
return ($model->info_category_id !== 11 && $model->info_category_id !== 15)?Html::a('<i class="icon-trash"></i>', $url, ['class'=>'black-txt tips del-confirm-subitems']):'';
```

It just checks against the values, separately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do multiple comparisons like this:

```
$a !== $b, $c
```

You can however, do it like this:

```
$a !== $b || $a !== $c
```

Or alternatively, you can use an array:

```
!in_array($a, [$b, $c])
```

Comment: That's always TRUE; change `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array with the IDs you want to exclude, then include it in the scope of your closure and check if the ID exists in the array with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$excluded = [11, 15];
'delete' => function($url, $model) use ($excluded) { 
     $url = Url::to(['category/delete/'.$model->info_category_id]);
     return (!in_array($model->info_category_id, $excluded))?Html::a('<i class="icon-trash"></i>', $url, ['class'=>'black-txt tips del-confirm-subitems']):'';
 },
```